# Flash CS5/Adobe AIR 2 - No preview

Tags: air, flash-cs5

Adobe Air 2/Flash CS5 on Win.

I must finish 2 little desktop projects in the client office right now. I have 6 hours to do it.

I did develop and test both apps at my studio and everything was OK. Even the installer generation. The client did test the beta installers in his computer.

Now I cant preview (ctrl+enter) them in my client computer, so I can't finish the projects and I'm 3 hours far away from home.

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

I did change the name of the files and..., voilà, it worked!

Weird situation this one!

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer to this question? That way this page will be helpful for other visitors.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved:**

I did change the name of both files and..., voilà, they came back to live!

Weird situation this one!